# error message: -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: terminal, syntax-error, unexpected-token

I am installing software, and the last line (here is the picture of my terminal [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaA4F.png)) delivers the message: -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('   . I was thinking that I need to insert a backward slash somewhere in between the parentheses in the command line that gave me the error message when I ran it. However, I am skeptical of having to change anything because this line is from NASA from a tutorial to install certain software (seems pretty official). Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're following the instructions at this website:
https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/lheasoft/install.html

And you've copied this command into your terminal

```
gunzip -c heasoft6.26(src|arch).tar.gz | tar xf -
```

The command isn't meant to be copied literally, the writers intend you replace the "(src|arch)" part to match the file you've downloaded.

Check what files exist in your directory by running `ls -l`
When you see the file you're looking for, run the command again with the correct filename.

For example if you downloaded the pre-compiled binary for OS X, run:

```
gunzip -c heasoft-6.26.1mac_intel_darwin18_patch.tar.gz | tar xf -
```

Comment: Also if you happen to have a lot of files in the directory, you can use the `find` command to find what you're looking for. EX: `find . -d 1 -name 'heasoft*.tar.tz`